# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { - Error when converting WebDriverio project to Typrscript

Tags: typescript, cucumber, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I am trying to convert my webdriver.io + cucumber project to Typescript by following https://webdriver.io/docs/typescript.html and getting the error message "Unexpected toke { ".
I am using WebDriver.io + TypeScript + Cucumber.

In wdio.conf.js, I have the cucumberOpts as below

```
cucumberOpts: {
    requireModule: [
            'tsconfig-paths/register',
        () => { require('ts-node').register({files: true}) },
    ],
    require: ['./src/step_definitions/*.ts'],
    backtrace: false,   
    requireModule: [],
    dryRun: false,      
    failFast: false,    
    format: ['pretty'], 
    colors: true,       
    snippets: true,     
    source: true,       
    profile: [],        
    strict: false,      
    tags: [],           
    timeout: 60000,     
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false,
},
```

And my tsconfig.json looks like below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": [ "./*" ],
        "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "types": ["node", "@wdio/sync","jest"]
  },

  "include": [
      "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

and my folder structure is as below

```
src/features/
src/step_definitions
src/pageObjects
```

And my Step definition has below as first statement

### step.ts

```
import { Given, When, Then } from "cucumber";
```

Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test":"./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js"
  },
```

When I run my tests, I am getting the error message " SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" on the above first line in my step.ts.

How do I fix this error.

Comment: Hey there! You get that error cause of the ES6 `import` statement. It looks like the compiler doesn't approve of the library version included. I'll try to draft an answer, but I'd also appreciate if you update the answer with the relevant `package.json` dependencies (`ts-node`, all the `@types`, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by compiling the Typescript files to Javascript files And then providing the location of Javascript files in the cucumberOpts => require

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, your `tsconfig.json` config file look OK, my only concern is with the `"target"` compiler option.

***Usually,*** with a `"target": "es6"` option, the following list of libraries would be injected: `DOM`, `ES6`, `DOM.Iterable` & `ScriptHost`. So `import` should not throw any error since the ES6 module library is included.

I'd try to explicitly suggest the library to the compiler via the `"lib"` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

The following worked for me:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
        "dom",
        "es7" // or es2016, es2017, es2018 ...
    ],
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": [ "./*" ],
        "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "types": ["node", "@wdio/sync","jest"]
  },
```

**!Note:** Other library versions include: `'ES3'` (*default*), `'ES5'`, `'ES2015'`, `'ES2016'`, `'ES2017'`,`'ES2018'`, or `'ESNEXT'`.